# Given the following tables/index/explain planning, why is the query so slow?

Tags: postgresql, index, join, explain

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE trace
(
  uuid uuid NOT NULL,
  result text,
  ruleid uuid,
  previousruleresultid uuid,
  senderduns text,
  receiverduns text,
  eventid uuid,
  relatedeventid uuid,
  emailrecipients text,
  emailbody text,
  created timestamp with time zone,
  identifierkeyvalues text,
  failuremessage text,
  errorflag boolean DEFAULT false,
  active boolean,
  carrier text,
  modified timestamp with time zone,
  processingmode numeric,
  currentstatus text,
  origin text,
  destination text,
  ontimestatus text,
  shipper text,
  deliveryrequesteddate timestamp without time zone,
  eventdate timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT traceruleresult_pk PRIMARY KEY (uuid),
  CONSTRAINT tracerule_fk FOREIGN KEY (ruleid)
      REFERENCES rule (uuid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE resultitem
(
  resultid uuid NOT NULL,
  type text NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  created timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT shipmentitem_pkey PRIMARY KEY (resultid, type, name),
  CONSTRAINT resultitem_resultid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (resultid)
      REFERENCES trace (uuid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

This is my query:

```
explain analyze select
    distinct trace.*
from
    Trace trace 
left outer join
    ResultItem resultitem2_ 
        on trace.uuid=resultitem2_.resultId 
where
    trace.errorFlag=false 
    and (
        trace.deliveryRequestedDate>= '2017-08-03T14:01:45.555Z' 
        or trace.deliveryRequestedDate is null
    ) 
    and (
        trace.deliveryRequestedDate<= '2017-08-24T14:01:45.555Z'
        or trace.deliveryRequestedDate is null
    ) 
    and (
        trace.previousRuleResultId is null
    ) 
order by
    trace.deliveryRequestedDate asc limit 15
```

This is the explain plan result:

```
'Limit  (cost=56463.26..56464.24 rows=15 width=709) (actual time=28542.669..28542.755 rows=15 loops=1)'
'  ->  Unique  (cost=56463.26..58530.39 rows=31802 width=709) (actual time=28542.666..28542.723 rows=15 loops=1)'
'        ->  Sort  (cost=56463.26..56542.77 rows=31802 width=709) (actual time=28542.662..28542.679 rows=15 loops=1)'
'              Sort Key: trace.deliveryrequesteddate, trace.uuid, trace.result, trace.ruleid, trace.previousruleresultid, trace.senderduns, trace.receiverduns, trace.eventid, trace.relatedeventid, trace.emailrecipients, trace.emailbody, trace.created, trace.identifierkeyvalues, trace.failuremessage, trace.errorflag, trace.active, trace.carrier, trace.modified, trace.processingmode, trace.currentstatus, trace.origin, trace.destination, trace.ontimestatus, trace.shipper, trace.eventdate'
'              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 88088kB'
'              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=39049.07..44081.98 rows=31802 width=709) (actual time=566.923..1281.588 rows=72427 loops=1)'
'                    Hash Cond: (resultitem2_.resultid = trace.uuid)'
'                    ->  Seq Scan on resultitem resultitem2_  (cost=0.00..1140.41 rows=54141 width=16) (actual time=0.005..115.204 rows=54062 loops=1)'
'                    ->  Hash  (cost=35793.54..35793.54 rows=31802 width=709) (actual time=566.765..566.765 rows=26961 loops=1)'
'                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 4075kB'
'                          ->  Seq Scan on trace  (cost=0.00..35793.54 rows=31802 width=709) (actual time=0.010..339.345 rows=26961 loops=1)'
'                                Filter: ((NOT errorflag) AND (previousruleresultid IS NULL) AND ((deliveryrequesteddate >= '2017-08-03 14:01:45.555'::timestamp without time zone) OR (deliveryrequesteddate IS NULL)) AND ((deliveryrequesteddate <= '2017-08-24 14:01:45.555'::timestamp without time zone) OR (deliveryrequesteddate IS NULL)))'
'                                Rows Removed by Filter: 147970'
'Planning time: 0.420 ms'
'Execution time: 28569.880 ms'
```

I'm having trouble seeing where the issue is. Clearly my left join is causing the slowness, as removing that join makes the query come back within milliseconds as opposed to almost 30 seconds. I'm not sure if it's an indexing issue as I have every column that's in the where clause indexed and the constraint in place. I feel like I'm missing something basic here but not sure what. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/GYEM shows the intermediate results are spilling to disk. Try bumping your `work_mem` up to 100MB or so (if you can the RAM for it).

Comment: I was looking at why the sort key uses every column in the table, and realize the distinct is what's causing the issue. How do I optimize this only return one of each trace record? If I remove the distinct and there are three resultitem associations, 3 get returned back

Comment: If you have the option to add more filters to your query, that's one solution. Another is to look at `DISTINCT ON ()`, per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: Why are you joining to resultitem in the first place?  It isn't restricting the rows returned, because it is a left join.  You aren't selecting or filtering on any columns from it, that I can tell.  All it does is causes duplications, which your comment indicates you don't want anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following indexes:

- trace.errorFlag
- trace.deliveryRequestedDate
- trace.previousRuleResultId
- resultitem.resultid

Comment: Yep, already did that

Answer (score 0):

Main problem at one glance

i) Data Type :Lot of text data type which will naturally make the heavy

ii)Writing optimize query

iii) suitable Index .

iv) PRIMARY KEY (resultid, type, name) : Here type and name is unlimited size and that part of PK which is not bad choice of for PK.If you can limit that size or change data type or any alternative solution.

In your query left join and trace.* is doing the trick,when you don't need result table column then why not use "Exists clause" to eliminate distinct.

so you can understand my query and convert it into POSTGRESQL,

```
select
     trace.result ,previousruleresultid ,mention other column that you need
from
    Trace trace 
where exists(select 1 from 
    ResultItem resultitem2_ 
        where  trace.uuid=resultitem2_.resultId )
and
    trace.errorFlag=false 
    and (
            ( trace.deliveryRequestedDate>= '2017-08-03T14:01:45.555Z' 
            and trace.deliveryRequestedDate<= '2017-08-24T14:01:45.555Z')
            or (  trace.deliveryRequestedDate is null ) 
        )

    and (
        trace.previousRuleResultId is null
    ) 
order by
    trace.deliveryRequestedDate asc limit 15
```

Comment: As noted in the comments, since no columns from `ResultItem` are returned, and since (due to its being a `LEFT JOIN`) it doesn't restrict the return of any rows, it can probably be left out entirely (based on the query as presented). With the `EXISTS` clause, it is restricting which rows are returned, so the results may not match up properly.

Comment: lovely @RDFozz , i got you and agree that it can be left out entirely,but suppose Daniel9x meant to filter then EXISTS will perform ok.It depend upon requirement only

Comment: Quite true - like I said, the comment was based on the query as presented. Since we don't know if the reason why `ResultItem` is there was "simplified" out of the query, or if it was included as "voodoo code" (copy/pasted from elsewhere, without understanding; when the filtering was unneeded, they changed it to a `LEFT JOIN` and left it in place, instead of removing it, because they didn't know why it was there). Still, I would be reluctant to deliberately present a solution that explicitly works differently than the original without commenting on it.